# Storing name, language mark ,english mark , and math mark. Getting the average of the three marks. I am not sure how to continue

Tags: java

This is how much I have done so far. 
I am unsure how to continue from here. 
Should I be using double for loops for a problem like this?

```
public class testing {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("How many people?");
        String input = sc.nextLine();
        int z = Integer.parseInt(input);
        for(int i =0; i <=z; i++) {
            System.out.println("Name,Language,English,Math?");
            String input2 = sc.nextLine();
            String[] myArr = new String[] {input2};

            for(int j = 0; j<4; j++) {
                String [] myArr1 = myArr[j].split(",");
                System.out.println(myArr1[0]);
            }
            //System.out.println(myArr[0]);
            //student student1 = new student(myArr[i]);
            for(int j = 0; j< 4; j++) {
                String[] studentpl = myArr[i].split(",");
            }
            //ArrayList<student> aList = new ArrayList<student>();
            //aList.add(input2);
            //student1 student new student1();
            //student stu = new student(input);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: There are two answers here. Any feedback?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to make a list that will hold all the students. Also it might be useful to make a student class that will hold the students attributes (name, language, english, math). After getting the input for the number of students to be processed you can loop in getting the students data. Once you get the student data from the input, make an instance of a Student class and set all those acquired data to the class. Once all data has been set you then add the Student to your student list. I have included a sample code below, but this code does not have error checking in the inputs. For example you can do checking if the input for numberOfStudents is valid. This code can be improved but for simplicity sake I have disregarded those checking.

Here is the main class

```
public class Testing {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("How many people?");
        int numberOfStudents = sc.nextInt();
        ArrayList<Student> studentList = new ArrayList<Student>();

        for(int i = 0; i < numberOfStudents; i++) {
            System.out.println("Name,Language,English,Math?");
            String dataInput = sc.nextLine();
            String[] dataInput = dataInput.split(",");
            // You can add here checking if the dataInput is valid. Example if it really contains all the needed input by checking the size of dataInput

            Student student = new Student();
            student.setName(dataInput[0]);
            student.setLanguage(dataInput[1]);
            student.setEnglish(dataInput[2]);
            student.setMath(dataInput[3]);
            studentList.add(student);
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the Student class. You should import this class to your main class.

```
public class Student {
     private name;
     private language;
     private english;
     private math;

     // insert here getter and setter methods for each attribute
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This should get you started:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("How many people?");
        int input = sc.nextInt(); sc.nextLine();
        ArrayList<Student> students = new ArrayList<Student>();

        for (int i = 0; i < input; i++) {
            System.out.println("Name, Language, English, Math?");

            String input2 = sc.nextLine();
            String[] myArr = input2.split("[, ]+");

            students.add(new Student(myArr[0], tryParse(myArr[1]), tryParse(myArr[2]), tryParse(myArr[3])));

        }

        for(Student s : students)
            System.out.println(s.name);

    }

    public static double tryParse(String grade) {
        return Double.parseDouble(grade);
    }

}

class Student{

    public String name;
    public double language;
    public double english;
    public double math;

    public Student(String name, double language, double english, double math) {
        this.name = name;
        this.language = language;
        this.english = english;
        this.math = math;
    }

}
```

Try not to start class names with lowercase letters. It's bad practice.